# what does .EXE file contains

Tags: java

Java .class file contains the java byte code. And at the runtime this .class file gets  loaded into the JVM. Then JVM executes the byte code. I want to know what this .exe  file contains(I am using Windows)? Do all variables gets the memory at .exe creation time or when this .exe file gets loaded onto the RAM?

Comment: Which .exe file? The JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXE files are very different from bytecode. They have code and a small preallocated section of memory that can be moved in which its variables lie. Any extra memory is allocated at runtime. Class files have bytecode that runs in the foreign address space of the EXE, and each instruction is read and parsed by native code in the EXE's address space.

Comment: Static variables gets memory at the class loading time ,when the .class file gets loaded into the JVM. So it means before creation of .exe by JVM static has got the memory?

Comment: @user2594479 No exe is created by the JVM. The JVM *is* an EXE.

Answer (score 2):

EXE or binary file contains machine instructions which is loaded in RAM at the program execution time. After then the CPU start executing those instruction serially. And that at end your computer completes what the EXE is intended to do.